# How can I declare string as with a paragraph with swift?

Tags: swift, string

I want to declare string with p paragraph by **swift**, like following, but not right, can anyone give me a favor?

**I don't want to declare string with one line**, which is not easy to read

```
let format = "<p><strong>%@ paddock selected</strong></p>
                        <p>Total Area %.1f ha</p>
                        <p>Effective Area %.1f ha</p>
                        <p></p>
                        <p><strong>%@</strong></p>
                        <p>Total Area %.1f ha</p>
                        <p>Effective Area %.1f ha</p>"
```

And I don't want somethings like following, I have to add `"` at leading and `" +` and trailing :(

```
let format = "<style>" +
                        "p {" +
                        "    margin: 1 1 1 1;" +
                        "}" +
                        "</style>" +
                        "<body>" +
                        "<p><strong>%@ paddock selected</strong></p>" +
                        "<p>Total Area %.1f ha</p>" +
                        "<p>Effective Area %.1f ha</p>" +
                        "<p></p>" +
                        "<p><strong>%@</strong></p>" +
                        "<p>Total Area %.1f ha</p>" +
                        "<p>Effective Area %.1f ha</p>" +
                        "</body>"
```

With `objective-c`, I just need to add `\` each line will be ok, but not well in swift

```
NSString* format = @"<p><strong>%@ paddock selected</strong></p>\
                        <p>Total Area %.1f ha</p>\
                        <p>Effective Area %.1f ha</p>\
                        <p></p>\
                        <p><strong>%@</strong></p>\
                        <p>Total Area %.1f ha</p>\
                        <p>Effective Area %.1f ha</p>";
```

Comment: I believe you can use `\n` to go to the next line

Comment: @penatheboss thanks for your reply, I don't to out put the break line, I just want to copy some sections to initialize  a string directly. in `ojbc`, i just need to add `\` in the end of line will be ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the multiline format into `Localizable.strings` (which also is the right place where to write strings).

[image]

> Please note that this method will actually add newline instructions at the end of each line! However this should not be a problem in your case since you are writing HTML.

### More

This is not directly related to your question, however you could also find useful this `String` extension

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }
}
```

since it does allow you to retrieve the localized version of your string simply writing

```
"Test".localized
```

Comment: I'm kicking myself for not thinking of that localization trick myself.

Comment: @NRitH: I found it somewhere (probably here on StackOverflow) a long time ago. And it made my code a lot cleaner.

Comment: A downside to this approach is that translators aren't getting any comments–which are extremely valuable pieces of information.

Comment: @wakachamo: Absolutely true.

Answer (score 3):

Swift lacks this feature. It has neither autoconcatenation of string literals nor here documents.   File a bug report if it's important to you.

What I do is load big strings, including format strings, as a text file from the app bundle.

Comment: Thank for your response, it is not so important for me, I just want to find some convenient way to to that. now I add `"` at leading and `" +` and trailing manully

Comment: Well, I told you a convenient way.